# Idea introduce variable customize variable name

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

When I use idea's `introduce variable` function, I want to customize the variable name, ex:
`Arrays.asList("asd");`
press `ctrl+alt+v`, will get
`List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("asd");`
by default but I want
`List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("asd");`
so I must change to `stringList` everytime by my self 
how to modify the `introduce variable` default result of the **variable name** so that I don't need to change it?

Comment: After running "Refactor | Introduce Variable" variable name should be highlighted and you may change it.

Comment: @y.bedrov
Thanks, but I want to get `List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("asd");` eveytime by default whitout any change.

Comment: It's not possible to set it as a default name, but it should be suggested in dropdown